# China Rising DLC

Tags: battlefield-4

I pre-ordered my BF4 and got the China rising DLC now I haven't got a chance to put in enough hours to be able to tell you if I played it. But by reading [this](http://bf4central.com/2013/10/battlefield-4-china-rising-dlc-launches-december-3rd/) post it says that the DLC isn't released till the 3rd of Dec. So does that mean even though I put in the code and downloaded the DLC I can't play it till that date?

Comment: Games nowadays often have content on the disc or ready at launch but labeled as DLC so the developers can make more money. This is because launch retail isn't enough to cover the rapidly climbing development costs, unless the game sells like GTA. It's kind of a necessary evil...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you will only be able to play *China Rising* when it's out. It was like that with BF3 Premium(when you got all DLC's, but could only play them when they were released).

**EDIT**

As [*vartec*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7354/vartec) mentioned in his comment:

It was the same with pre-order of BF3 when you also got *Back to Karkand* DLC, but you could only start playing it after it was officially released.

Comment: The pre-order BF3 was called Limited Edition and just like pre-order BF4 came with one DLC. In case of BF3 it was B2K, which was released in early December (i.e. 2 months after after base game release).

Comment: @vartec I was talking about **Premium**, which granted you *all* DLCs, but they were only playable after they were officially released

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is wrong. Thing is situation with pre-order BF4 is **exactly** the same as it was with pre-order BF3.